# Possible to ffmpeg encode an MP3 media segment for HLS to follow existing MP3?

Tags: mp3, encoding, ffmpeg, streaming

My use case is essentially DIY internet radio. I've abstracted the real-world constraints into a toy problem for simplicity, but these constraints are real for me.

I'm shipping a 24/7 live HLS stream with only MP3 files. In a perfect world, the catch is that to support high fault tolerance, and these MP3 files are all individually generated from the source WAV files.

I've gotten a test version working with ffmpeg running inside of another process that feeds PCM data to its stdin:

```
ffmpeg \
    -v info \
    -i pipe:0 \
    -f hls \
    -ac 2 \
    -c:a mp3 \
    -b:a 128k \
    -initial_offset 12345 \
    -maxrate 128k \
    -minrate 128k \
    -start_number 12345 \
    -hls_flags delete_segments \
    -hls_list_size 20 \
    -hls_playlist_type event \
    -hls_segment_filename /tmp/radio-%d.mp3 \
    -hls_time 10
```

Ideally, I can consume that stream using `ffplay` without errors.

However, when I perfectly replicate the output of that `ffmpeg -f hls` process above using manual ffmpeg runs, we hear audio discontinuities, tiny pieces of silent mortar between the bricks of audio. The reason for this is known. See this answer to this question on video StackExchange: [Audio discontinuities when generating HLS segments in different processes](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/34627/audio-discontinuities-when-generating-hls-segments-in-different-processes#answer-34629):

Here's the `ffmpeg` I've got so far encoding from WAV files that we write to a temp folder on disk in advance of this step:

```
ffmpeg \
    -i pathToWAV \
    -id3v2_version 0 \
    -ac 2 \
    -c:a mp3 \
    -b:a 128k \
    -minrate 128k \
    -maxrate 128k \
    /tmp/radio-12345.wav
```

**Is there some way** to tell ffmpeg to use the last 1024 frames from the previously-encoded MP3 (e.g. radio-12344.mp3) in the transform overlapping the first 1024 frames of the next MP3 media segment in the HLS? Or maybe to do a second pass on each file using a muxer where I lop off those priming samples?

Comment: The best solution I've come up with so far is essentially the first version above where I run ffmpeg continuously outputting a whole HLS playlist based on stdin.

What I figured out is that if I always discard the first segment generated when said process starts up (the first MP3 in the series is the only one that begins with priming frames) and I use a media segment numbering system that is totally deterministic from any given epoch seconds, then I can more-or-less idempotently generate my segments, per my fault tolerance constraints.

Answer (score 1):

The Thing Is, you are not perfectly replicating the output of -f hls by doing what you are doing. You are creating discrete mp3's and expecting them to behave the same way as hls mp3's. HLS is designed to produce mp3's that are a continuous stream of concatenatable files. Discrete mp3's cannot be concatenated in he way you are attempting.

Also, check this:

https://github.com/huhani/mp3-to-hls

Comment: That's right. However, it is certainly theoretically possible to do what I describe, if one could rehydrate its codec using the last 1024 frames from the previous media segment. The question is whether ffmpeg has this flexibility. In the meantime, I have posted an interesting trick I figured out in a comment on the original post.

Comment: Yes, but I think that's what -f hls is doing.